# Not all the props that get passed down is rendered anyone have an idea as to why

Tags: reactjs, firebase

After I recieved the data from firebase and store it into the post state and I try to pass each data to another component one one data is been sent to the prop anyone have.

Any idea as to why?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BlogPost from './BlogPost'
import firebase from '../../config/fbConfig'

class BlogList extends Component {
    state = {
        posts: []
    }
    componentDidMount() {

        const db = firebase.firestore()
        db.collection('posts').get().then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.docs.forEach(post => {
                let id = post.id
                let postData = post.data()
                postData['id'] = id
                this.setState({
                    posts: [...this.state.posts, postData]
                })
            })

        })

    }


    render() {
        console.log(this.state.posts)

        return (
            <>
                {this.state.posts ?
                    this.state.posts.map(post =>
                        <BlogPost post={post} key={post.id} />
                    )
                    : <h1>loading</h1>}

            </>
        );
    }
}

export default BlogList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in how you update the state, you must either use `functional setState` since you call setState within a loop and use `this.state.data` to update state, but state updates are not performed immediately but happen asynchronously

```
componentDidMount() {

    const db = firebase.firestore()
    db.collection('posts').get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach(post => {
            let id = post.id
            let postData = post.data()
            postData['id'] = id
            this.setState(prev => ({
                posts: [...prev.posts, postData]
            }))
        })

    })

}
```

or even better update once all the data is available

```
componentDidMount() {

    const db = firebase.firestore()
    db.collection('posts').get().then(async snapshot => {
        const data = snapshot.docs.map(post => {
            let id = post.id
            let postData = post.data()
            postData['id'] = id
            return postData;
        });
        this.setState(prev => ({
            posts: [...prev.posts, ...data]
        }));

    })

}
```